# Idiomatic Python iterating and adding to a dict

Tags: python

I'm running through a string, creating all substrings of size 10, and adding them to a dict. This is my code,

```
sequence_map = {}
for i in range(len(s)):
    sub = s[i:i+10]
    if sub in sequence_map:
       sequence_map[sub] += 1
    else:
       sequence_map[sub] = 1
```

Is there a way to do this more pythonically?

Also how do I do the reverse pythonically, as in interating through the dict and composing a list where value is equal to something?

```
[k for k, v in sequence_map.items()]
```

Comment: Yes, use a `collections.Counter` object. so `sequence_map = Counter(s[i:i+10] for i in range(len(s))`

Comment: also don't forget that you really only want to iterate up to `range(len(s)) - 10`

Comment: Presumably you know that this won't produce all substrings of length 10 exclusively, due to the perplexingly forgiving nature of slicing in Python. In case you don't, you'll want to do `for i in range(len(s) - 9)`.

Comment: The second part of your question is unclear. The example does not match the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` which is "smart" enough to add missing keys as needed:

```
from collections import defaultdict
sequence_map = defaultdict(int)
for i in range(len(s) - 10):
    sub = s[i:i + 10]
    sequence_map[sub] += 1
```

As for the second part of your question, are you looking for this?

```
[k for k, v in sequence_map.items() if v==something]
```

Comment: Ah, beat me to it! I had the exact same code typed up. +1

Comment: I've modified the question a little bit to add a little more query. I could totally accept your answer anyway, but I've feel you might know the answer to the second part as well.

Comment: I added a conditional answer to the second question.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, as @juanpa.arrivillaga said in the comments, you can use `collections.Counter` to easily do this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = 'abcde' * 30 # test value
>>> sequence_map = Counter(s[i:i + 10] for i in range(len(s) - 9))
>>> sequence_map
Counter({'abcdeabcde': 29, 'bcdeabcdea': 28, 'cdeabcdeab': 28, 'deabcdeabc': 28, 'eabcdeabcd': 28})
```